# ASP.NET Core - Protect content page with access code confirmation

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm developing an ASP.NET Core MVC web application where the single user can create a `Room` entity and protect the visualization of the details with a security code. Basically every user that knows the security code can access the page.

Which is the proper way to handle this?

`Index.cshtml`:

```
@foreach (var room in Model.Rooms)
{
<form asp-controller="Rooms" asp-action="Detail" method="POST">
    <!-- Button trigger modal -->
    <input type="hidden" name="RoomId" value="@room.RoomId" />

    @if (room.Owner.Id == currentUserId)
    {
        <input type="hidden" class="form-control" name="AccessCode" value="@room.AccessCode">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket"></i>
        </button>
    }
    else
    {
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#roomModal-@room.RoomId">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-right-to-bracket"></i>
        </button>

        <!-- Modal -->
        <div class="modal fade" id="roomModal-@room.RoomId" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="roomModal-@room.RoomId" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="roomModal-@room.RoomId-Label">Enter in @room.Name</h1>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-12">
                                    <label for="AccessCode" class="form-label">Enter the access code</label>
                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" required name="AccessCode">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</form>
}
```

RoomsController:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Detail(InputRoomDetailViewModel input) 
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");

    var room = await _roomsService.Query(new RoomsService.RoomQuery()
            {
                RoomId = input.RoomId
            });

    if (input.AccessCode != room.AccessCode) 
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }

    var model = new RoomDetailViewModel()
            {
                RoomOwner = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User),
                RoomId = input.TableId,
                RoomName = room.Name
            };

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: "Proper"? Does your code work or not? If not tell us what is not working.

Comment: The code is working, but i would appreciate to know, in general, if there is a best fit for what i'm trying to do. For example if it is correct to handle the access code as a string

Comment: If you're asking about security, I think your code it's ok. Using HTTPS the communication is secured and so also the content for `AccessCode` input field.

About usability I think that you could think about an access point that include the access code in the url so that you don't have to pass by a form and send a link to the user to access the room. I add that you could include the check about current user in the controller and check for access code only if the user is not the owner.